# storing multiple array values in single with order

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays:

```
$arr1=array(0,5,2,3,4,5);
$arr2=array(0,5,2,3,4,5);
$arr3=array(0,5,2,3,4,5);

I want to store their value in 4th array like below:

$arr4=array(0,0,0,5,5,5,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5);
```

pls input

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr4 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
asort($arr4);
```

**EDIT**

Sorry. `asort` doesn't sort the way you want.

You can use a callback for sorting, but this works only if every of your input arrays has the same element count.

```
$arr4 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

$length = count($arr1);
uksort($arr4, function($k1, $k2) use($length) {
    $sort = $k1%$length - $k2%$length;
    if ($sort == 0) $sort = floor($k1/$length) - floor($k2/$length);
    return $sort;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3); //you can pass multiple array 
asort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: @stefandoorn ellipse is the indication of number of argument can be passed